# Separate portfolio items. wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I want to seperste all the portfolio items into different pages,to get, let say, one page with one Portfolio Categories, next one with another Portfolio Categories.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Kirk, the question is "Can you do it for me?"

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one archive template for the portfolio categories or the taxonomy. Please read this: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/

Lemme know if this helps!